# How do I display my months in ascending order (Jan, Feb, Mar) through a gt table in R?

Tags: r, date, datatables, lubridate, gt

I have my two chunks of code below. In the first chunk I am trying to get my data ready to display in a gt table. My goal is to display a table with Month abbreviations in ascending order (Jan, Feb, March, etc.) in column 1. Currently, it appears each time I run the second chunk of code to create a table, it sort the month data alphabetically. I have looked into the lubridate package, messed around with the 'month.abb' and 'month.name function and still am outputting the months in alphabetical order. See packages used below and chunks below.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(quantmod)
library(tidyquant)
library(xts)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(forcats)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)
library(plotly)
library(purrr)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(gt)
library(paletteer)
library(readr)
library(janitor)
library(scales)
library(lubridate)
```

#### Obtain and Clean Data To Feed Into gt (Chunk 1)

```
start <- as.Date("2020-01-01")
end <- as.Date("2020-11-30")
StockMonthlyReturns <- c("XLC", "XLC", "XLP", "XLE","XLF", "XLV", "XLI","XLB", "XLRE", "XLK", "XLU") %>%
  tq_get(get = "stock.prices", 
         from = start,
         to = end) %>%
  group_by(symbol) %>%
  tq_transmute(select = adjusted,
               mutate_fun = periodReturn,
               period = "monthly",
               col_rename = "StockMonthlyReturns")

stockdata <- StockMonthlyReturns %>% group_by(symbol, Month = floor_date(date, "month")) %>% summarise(Amount = sum(StockMonthlyReturns))
monthnum <- month(stockdata$Month)
stockdata <- cbind(stockdata, monthnum)
stockdata <- stockdata %>% rename(Month_Num = ...4)
stockdata$Month_Num <- month.abb[stockdata$Month_Num]
stockdata <- stockdata %>% 
  select(-Month)
stockdata <-  stockdata %>% rename(Month = "Month_Num")
#stockdata$Month <- months(as.Date(stockdata$Month))
stockdata <- adorn_rounding(stockdata, digits= 4) # Rounding Returns 
stockdata$Amount <- percent(stockdata$Amount, accuracy = 0.01) # Changing Decimals to Percent
```

### Using dplyr to Graph Data using gt (Chunk 2)

```
stockdata %>% 
  tidyr::spread(key="symbol", value = Amount) %>%
  gt(rowname_col = "Month") %>%
  tab_header(title = "Monthly Return of SPDR ETF's")
```

Comment: @RonakShah included, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try :

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

stockdata %>% 
  mutate(Month = factor(Month, month.abb)) %>%
  tidyr::spread(key=symbol, value = Amount) %>%
  #tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = symbol, values_from= Amount) %>%
  gt(rowname_col = "Month") %>%
  tab_header(title = "Monthly Return of SPDR ETF's")
```

[image]

Also note that `spread` has been retired in favor of `pivot_wider`.